# Nginx and js/css versioning via browser's cache

Tags: nginx, cache

I want to easily clear the browser's cache when js/css files are updated.

Real file location:

- /js/some-files.js
- /css/some-files.css

File location set in the app to be called by browser:

- /js/v1/some-files.js
- /css/v1/some-files.css

I tried the following but going to */js/v1/some-files.js* gives me 404s.

```
location ~ ^/(js|css)/v[0-9]+/(.*)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 7d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/$2;
}
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably the try_files directive that should probably read like... `try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;`

Comment: Well that was easy! It was that missing slash!

Comment: Glad to know it works. Posting it as answer, if you wish to upvote or select it as the best answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to missing slash, as mentioned in the comments! Additionally, your [location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) block can be simplified like the following...

```
location ~ /(js|css)/v[0-9]+/(.*) {
    access_log off;
    expires 7d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint (the missing slash)! Looks like the `~` is however still required to trigger regular expression.

Comment: This issue also deviated to another issue… if you wish please [check out my other quesiton](http://serverfault.com/questions/538890/nginx-expires-header-not-working)

Comment: You're right. I've fixed it. Will look into the other issue now.