# Nginx: expires header not working

Tags: nginx

I'm having issues with the `expires` header field. The following nginx rules give me this header (no expire header). Ideas why the expires headers arn't being passed?

**Header for: /css/v1/afile.css**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2013 07:29:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 12548
Last-Modified: Sat, 11 May 2013 11:05:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root    /var/www/apps/myapp/public/app/webroot;
    index   index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_tokens off;

    access_log  /var/www/apps/myapp/logs/access.log;
    error_log   /var/www/apps/myapp/logs/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /(js|css)/v[0-9]+/(.*) {
        access_log off;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
    }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files not found
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work to display the expires header that was set in the same location block...

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2 =404;
```

As per Nginx wiki, [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) should end with a URI or with a status code. You may get more information on why expires aren't set, if you enable [debugging in Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Debugging).

**Update**:

> Ideas why the expires headers arn't being passed?

I enabled debugging to figure out this interesting situation. This is what I found...

Here's a direct quote from the try_files wiki article linked earlier...

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri
>   specified in the last parameter is made.

So, when you used the following code...

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
```

the nginx could not find `$uri` and `$uri/` (in your case /css/v1/afile.css and /css/v1/afile.css/), an internal redirect to the URI specified in the last parameter is made. So, after the internal redirect, the location `/$1/$2` is found (in your case /css/afile.css), *in another location block*. Since, it is executed by another location block that doesn't have any expires, you didn't see expires.

Comment: Wow — Amazing! Extremely insightful! Thanks for looking deeply into this matter. Now I understand why I saw lots of `try_files` rule end with `=404;`

Comment: It's my pleasure to have learned something from this issue.